# Inheriting from Protractor's ElementFinder type without getting typescript warnings

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am getting compilation warnings when attempting to `extend ElementFinder` from Protractor in typescript.

> package.json

```
"typescript": "^2.0.0-dev.20160707"
"typings": "^1.3.1"
"protractor": "3.3.0"
```

In my project, I have installed [typing definitions from definitely typed](https://github.com/Droogans/encore-ui/blob/setup-typescript/utils/rx-page-objects/typings.json), and so far everything works great.

However, once I [imported the `ElementFinder` class from protractor directly](https://github.com/Droogans/encore-ui/blob/38b08860a59bc4932b8c8f34dfc162c09bab1eb6/utils/rx-page-objects/src/rxDatePicker.page.ts#L13), it began referring to the `built` directory's `element.d.ts` file for typing information. For some reason, the exported typing information says that everything is returning a `webdriver.Promise`, when the source code (and even the documentation in the generated `built/` javascript!) says that the type is `webdriver.promise.Promise`.

I am getting the following compilation warnings on this [typescript file that represents a datepicker in our component library](https://github.com/Droogans/encore-ui/blob/38b08860a59bc4932b8c8f34dfc162c09bab1eb6/utils/rx-page-objects/src/rxDatePicker.page.ts).

```
node_modules/protractor/built/element.d.ts(58,31): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/element.d.ts(60,106): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/element.d.ts(222,24): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/element.d.ts(255,36): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/element.d.ts(280,54): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/element.d.ts(303,35): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/element.d.ts(336,37): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/element.d.ts(368,62): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/element.d.ts(642,37): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/protractor.d.ts(96,22): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/protractor.d.ts(201,57): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/protractor.d.ts(214,57): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/protractor.d.ts(221,93): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/protractor.d.ts(313,41): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/protractor.d.ts(322,36): error TS2305: Module 'webdriver' has no exported member 'Promise'.
```

This is strange since I am seeing that my `rxDatePicker` instances show up with all the methods and properties of an `ElementFinder`, so the generated javascript is being created, I'm just seeing a lot of warnings.

Perhaps there is a way to ignore the warnings? Is there a way to do that instead?

Comment: Hi ! Did you find out what happened? I'm getting a similar error

Comment: Sure, the project that this occurred in is open source, the pull request that dealt with all of it is https://github.com/rackerlabs/encore-ui/pull/1789. Pay attention to https://github.com/rackerlabs/encore-ui/blob/73617a11a232300c5b05a0f7d3359f31e675e95d/utils/rx-page-objects/typings.json and https://github.com/rackerlabs/encore-ui/blob/73617a11a232300c5b05a0f7d3359f31e675e95d/utils/rx-page-objects/src/rxDatePicker.page.ts#L1-L4 for a good idea of how I got around those errors.

Answer (score 1):

In case you did not find it already this is the temporary solution:

In package.json ensure this line is at 2.44.*
  "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.*",